# how to upload image to public folder not to storage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to upload images to public folder inside imgs folder so I tried adding to cofig/filesystems.php the following:

```
'pub' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => '/imgs',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
```

but now when I use `$d->storeAs('products', $name.$ext, ['storage' => 'pub']);` the images are saved inside storage/app/public/imgs/products not public/imgs/products

how I store them in public not in storage?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why do you want to use public folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you now have to do this in config/filesystems.php .

You can add a new disk like so:

```
'disks' => [
  'uploads' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root'   => public_path(), // previously storage_path();
   ],
]
```

and then do the following to use it:

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

References :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-the-storage-path-to-public-laravel-53